# React TypeScript: (props: OwnProps) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

As a JSX element, all is good...

```
interface OwnProps {
  children: JSX.Element;
  location: Location;
}

export function Layout(props: OwnProps): JSX.Element {
```

When I change it to a functional component I get an error on `Layout`

```
interface OwnProps {
  children: JSX.Element;
  location: Location;
}

const Layout: React.FC = (props: OwnProps) => {
```

The Error is

```
Type '(props: OwnProps) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Property 'location' is missing in type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' but required in type 'OwnProps'.ts(2322)
layout.tsx(18, 3): 'location' is declared here.
```

Comment: try `const Layout: React.FC<OwnProps> = (props) => {`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

React.FC is actually a generic type. You need to specify your prop type

```
const Layout: React.FC<OwnProps> = (props: OwnProps) => {}
```